# Migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL, Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, migration

I have to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL. Please find the some of the problems which I mentioned here.

When starting the application, the error messages with each entity and associations `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "local_string" does not exist

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    ... 109 common frames omitted
```

When running the project again, the occurring some other error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "roles" does not exist

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    ... 110 common frames omitted
```

Full stack (main stack that does not change, except for the last part (see above)): https://gist.github.com/orlovleo12/188a9c2c98628b45e4b150afc6710092

These errors throws for all entities. All entities are made in one structure. Below is an example of a typical entity:

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "book", schema = "hib")
public class Book {
public Book(LocaleString nameLocale, LocaleString author) {
        this.name = nameLocale;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Book(Long id, OriginalLanguage originalLanguage, Long price, String coverImage) {
        this.id = id;
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
        this.price = price;
        this.coverImage = coverImage;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private LocaleString name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private LocaleString author;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private LocaleString description;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private LocaleString edition;

    private String yearOfEdition;

    private Long pages;

    private Long price;

    private String coverImage;

    private String originalLanguageName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Singular("listImage")
    private List<Image> listImage;

    private Long views;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private OriginalLanguage originalLanguage;

    private boolean isShow;

    @OneToOne
    private Category category;
}
```

After that, it seemed to me that the problem with entities disappeared, but after that there was a problem with relationship (example below):

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "book", schema = "hib")
public class Book {
```

After that, it seemed to me that the problem with entities disappeared, but after that there was a problem with connections (example below):

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "book_list_image" does not exist
```

Example relationship in Book entity

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Singular("listImage")
private List<Image> listImage;
```

and in  Image :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class Image {

    public Image(String nameImage) {
        this.nameImage = nameImage;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String nameImage;
}
```

But , I have table - book_list_image in DB.

**UPDATE:** I resolved problem with entity. But I am not able to understand the problem whether it is with the relationship for one-to-many and many-to-many. I got ERROR :
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "book_list_image" does not exist

Comment: So You are telling that this was working perfectly with MySQL, and only started these problems once tried with Posgres?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Yes, you  are right

Comment: How did you create tables in db? via jpa or manually? If manually most probably the problem should be with your tables. Can you show you tables in db?

Comment: I created tables with https://github.com/AnatolyUss/nmig . .
https://prnt.sc/sid7mq

Comment: for example book https://prnt.sc/sid844

Comment: Can't really give an answer with only the details of 'book' relation. However the best way is to generate your db is the JPA. Actually that's one of prime aspects of using JPA. It will probably help to overcome number of pitfalls like these.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I can create entity tables. I write (@)Table (name = "book", schema = "hib") instead of (@)Table (name = "book") (for example with book). The table is created.https://prnt.sc/sidgsr
But I have a problem with "manyToMany" and another relationship. PosgreSQL doesn't create tables with (for example) "ManyToMany."
How can I solve it?(https://prnt.sc/sidgjz)

Comment: Did you try the `application.properties` option `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` to test if it works on a `test` database?

Comment: Yes Nikhil. jpa create table for Entity without relationship for one-to-many and many-to-many. For relationship for one-to-many and many-to-many I got  I got ERROR : Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "book_list_image" does not exist.

Comment: Postgres cannot create such a table.